# Printing data on new page in HTML CSS after foreach loop

Tags: php, css, printing

I am working on an invoice systems, I am using foreach loop to view printable data, what I need is to start printing on new page every time foreach loop executing completed,
like on first print view page first executing data displayed and on second executing print view page automatically starts form 2nd page.

I tried `<p style="break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>` but it is adding only a line break instead of adding a page break.

My HTML file code is

```
   <?php 
    foreach ($production_codes as $key => $production_code) { 
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td><h6 class="font-12"><u>Size</u></h6></td>
                                  <td><h6 class="font-12"><u>No of Cartons</u></h6></td>
                                  <td><h6 class="font-12"><u>PCS per corton</u></h6></td>
                                  <td><h6 class="font-12"><u>Current Shipment</u></h6></td></tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
   }?>
```

Current print view is [image]

Comment: What are you expecting a new page to look like?

Comment: same printing / invoice design (html) but new data according to provided parameters in query in foreach loop...